# jQuery Tools issue in IE 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

jQuery Tools doesn't appear to initialise in IE 7. IE 7 says there's an issue on line 240, character 3.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slidertabs").jtTabs("#slider-content > p", {
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
            current: 'active',
            rotate: true,
        }).slideshow({autoplay: true, interval: 6000, clickable: false}); // <-- line 240
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery do you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE7 doesn't like it when there are commas following the final list item, as for in your JavaScript object on the line before line 240.

Remove the comma from the last item, and it should be fine.

Updated code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slidertabs").jtTabs("#slider-content > p", {
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
            current: 'active',
            rotate: true // removed comma from here
        }).slideshow({autoplay: true, interval: 6000, clickable: false}); // <-- line 240
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Must be like below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slidertabs").jtTabs("#slider-content > p", {
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
            current: 'active',
            rotate: true
        }).slideshow({autoplay: true, interval: 6000, clickable: false});
    });
</script>
```